# Clean solution to output XML-data in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have an XML-file, which contains various options for a PowerShell-script and I am looking for an clean and easy way to output them at the start of the script-execution. I don't want to use a special module.

The XML basically looks like this:

```
[xml]$Xml = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Parent>
  <Option1>Value</Option1>
  <Option2>True</Option2>
  <NestedOption>
    <NestedOption1>Value</NestedOption1>
    <NestedOption2>Value</NestedOption2>
  </NestedOption>
  <Option3>Value</Option3>
</Parent>
"@

$Xml.Parent
```

As you see there are nested nodes containing data too. (1 Level)
I was looking around, but I did not find a nice way to output this in PowerShell.
Maybe there are built-in functions or anybody has already created a solution?
Of course, the output should not be defined somehow statically.

The optimum output would look somehow like the output of "Get-WindowsFeature" below:

[image: Output of "Get-WindowsFeature"]

Thank you

Comment: You should recursively create some kind of lines. You should take into account: node has subnodes; node has attributes; node is not unique at its level; type can be parsed as Int, Float, Guid, String etc...

Answer (score 0):

Try [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table?view=powershell-6#parameters) cmdlet with property expressions:

```bsh
$Xml.Parent | Format-Table -Property @(
    @{ Label = 'Option 1';        Expression = 'Option1' }
    @{ Label = 'Option 2';        Expression = 'Option2' }
    @{ Label = 'Nested Option 1'; Expression = { $_.NestedOption.NestedOption1 } }
    @{ Label = 'Nested Option 2'; Expression = { $_.NestedOption.NestedOption2 } }
    @{ Label = 'Option 3';        Expression = 'Option3' }
)
```

Comment: Hello, I think this is just a static solution. Yes, this works on my sample. If I add another option in the XML-file, I would have to change the Format-Table properties too. This is not the way to go.

Comment: @DukeDonnovan Understandable. By the way, `Get-WindowsFeature` has a static solution too for this problem.